# Commenting a block of folded code causes it to unfold in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, code-folding

let's say I have a simple javascript method.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

If I fold this in visual studio code and comment it, the code unfolds automatically. Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to use block comments to comment folded code and have it remain folded.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: Hmmm, definitely doesn't unfold for me.